# AWS EC2 (ubuntu 20.04) its show Instance status checks fail error , how to find Root cause of issue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, aws-devops

In my aws account ec2 t2-medium instance. From yesterday onward my server is not loading and I am not able to SSH to this instance. when i see machine its show instance status check fail but when stop and start machine problem gone but how to find root cause of issue   ?

Comment: It's the issue from the AWS site (maybe servers or network ...). Normally you will receive an email from AWS.

Comment: No not from AWS side not getting email  generally system check fail that issue from aws side instance status check fail not aws side

Comment: As I mentioned, it is the issue from the AWS side (servers, network ...) That's why you need to design HA, multi-AZ ...

Comment: In general when this happens to me I take a look at the O/S log files.  Things like `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/kern.log`.  You'll need to be able to log into the machine though - can you after a reboot?  What is running on the machine?

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's a hardware issue. Whenever you launch your instance, AWS always monitors the health of your EC2 instance. There might be multiple reasons for status check failure :-

- Networking or startup configuration issues
- Exhausted memory
- File system issues
- Failure to boot the operating system
- Failure to mount volumes correctly
- Incompatible drivers
- CPU exhaustion

Whenever you stop & start, the instance AWS shifts your instance to new Hardware (As behind the seen it uses xen virtualization) & problem is solved.
For identifying the **root cause** of status check failure, **you can retrive the system logs**. For retriving system logs :
***`Select the instance -> goto Action -> monitor & troubleshoot -> Get system logs`***

For more information please check [AWS Doc](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstances.html)